# What am I doing wrong in my coin flip code?

Tags: python, debugging, python-3.x, attributeerror

I am trying to write a program that flips a coin, and displays Heads or Tails accordingly. This is what I have:

```
    from random import random
    while True:

        for i in range (2):
            spin = i.random()
            if spin == 0:
                print ("Heads")
            else:
                print ("Tails")
```

but I keep getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Yamnel/Desktop/Python Programs/coin flip.py", line 5, in     <module>
    spin = i.random()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'random'
```

Comment: How many times you want to toss the coin ? Infinite times? `while True` ?

Comment: You go on forever when using 'while True:' without a clause to stop the loop.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you [read the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/random.html) for the `random` module.  I suspect that you're probably going to be more interested in [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/random.html#random.choice) or [`random.randomrange()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/random.html#random.randrange) than you will be in `random.random()`.

Comment: Thanks Doug R, I'll read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random

while True:
    result = random.randrange(2)
    if result == 0:
       print ("Heads")
    else:
       print ("Tails")
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up following your instructions.

Answer (score 2):

See the following snippet

```
from random import random
coin = ['Heads', 'Tails']
num_of_tosses = 10
for i in range (num_of_tosses):
    spin = randrange(0,2)
    print coin[spin]
```

I am using `randrange` to randomly select elements from 0 to 1. In other words, to select 0 or 1.

Then I am setting a list of choices, called `coin`, that is used for printing `Tails` or `Heads`.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the solutions presented here focus on `random.randrange()`.  You can also do this using [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/random.html#random.choice), which returns a random element from a non-empty sequence:

```
>>> from random import choice
>>> coin = 'Heads Tails'.split()
>>> FLIPS = 5
>>> for _ in range(FLIPS):
...   print(choice(coin))
...
Tails
Heads
Tails
Heads
Tails
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
from random import randrange
while True:
        spin = randrange(0,2)
        if spin == 0:
            print ("Heads")
        else:
            print ("Tails")
```

Also how many times you want your code to run. This will never end. Ideally you will want your code to run once just to get `heads` or `tails`. I suggest to remove `while` from code. Also keep an eye on indentation if you remove `while`.

Answer (score 0):

"int" is a basic type that doesn't have methods like random().

You have to use random.randrange(2)

For more information see:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html (The Official Doc)

Comment: You may want to quote the relevant portions of the documentation.  Frankly, this is probably more of a comment on the OP, rather than an answer.

Comment: Thanks, but since I don't have the privilege of commenting yet, this was all I was able to do.